# Rounded imageview with getDrawingCache issue android

Tags: android, xml, image-processing, layout, screenshot

I am working on Photo Collage App and i have issue with rounded framelayout .The issue is when i apply rounded **drawable** as a background of framelayout and then i getting screenshot of that layout,i am getting different screenshot(without round corner).

[here is original layout with round corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPlS0.png)

[here is **screenshot** after apply round corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC78p.png)

This functionality use for apply round corner to framelayout

```
shapeDrawable1 = new GradientDrawable();
        shapeDrawable1.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        shapeDrawable1.setCornerRadius(50);
        shapeDrawable1.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transpernt));

  fl_Container_Fragment.setBackground(shapeDrawable1);
        fl_Container_Fragment.setClipToOutline(true);
```

This Function use for screenshot :

```
 private Bitmap getMainFrameBitmap(FrameLayout fl_frag) {
        fl_frag.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(fl_frag.getDrawingCache());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            bitmap.setConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }
        fl_frag.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        Bitmap bmp = bitmap;

        int imgHeight = bmp.getHeight();
        int imgWidth = bmp.getWidth();
        int smallX = 0, largeX = imgWidth, smallY = 0, largeY = imgHeight;
        int left = imgWidth, right = imgWidth, top = imgHeight, bottom = imgHeight;
        for (int i = 0; i < imgWidth; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < imgHeight; j++) {
                if (bmp.getPixel(i, j) != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                    if ((i - smallX) < left) {
                        left = (i - smallX);
                    }
                    if ((largeX - i) < right) {
                        right = (largeX - i);
                    }
                    if ((j - smallY) < top) {
                        top = (j - smallY);
                    }
                    if ((largeY - j) < bottom) {
                        bottom = (largeY - j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d("Trimed bitmap", "left:" + left + " right:" + right + " top:" + top + " bottom:" + bottom);
        return bmp;
    }
```

Please suggest me.
Thanks

Comment: tried to call `fl_frag.draw(Canvas)` directly?

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is useful for you.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainFrm = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainFrm);
        img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
        img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img2);

        screnshot = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_screenshot);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_screenshot);
        seek_round = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_round);
        bitmap = drawableToBitmap(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic1));
        seek_round.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                bitmap = getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap, i);
                img1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                img2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
        img1.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap, 250));
        img2.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap, 250));
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                screnshot.setImageBitmap(getMainFrameBitmap(mainFrm));
            }
        });
    }
```

This function convert drawable to bitmap

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
Bitmap bitmap = null;

if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
    if (bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
        return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
    }
}

if (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
} else {
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
drawable.draw(canvas);
return bitmap;
}
```

Use this function for get Rounded Corner Bitmap :

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
        .getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

final int color = 0xff424242;
final Paint paint = new Paint();
final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
final float roundPx = pixels;

paint.setAntiAlias(true);
canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
paint.setColor(color);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

return output;
}
```

xml File of Activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.lcom56.roundcornerimagedemo.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainFrm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/pic1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/pic1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek_round"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="1000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_screenshot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:text="Take Screenshot" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_screenshot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_screenshot"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

:[here is Output Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQMfy.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is second solution for you.

You can use Round corner Framelayout (custom Framelayout)

RoundCornerFramelayout.java

```
package com.example.pc.roundcornerimagedemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class RoundCornerFramelayout extends FrameLayout {
    private float CORNER_RADIUS = 50.0f;

    private Bitmap maskBitmap;
    private Paint paint, maskPaint;
    private float cornerRadius;
    private float oldRadius;
    private boolean isFirstTime = true;

    public RoundCornerFramelayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0);
    }

    public RoundCornerFramelayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public RoundCornerFramelayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setCORNER_RADIUS(float CORNER_RADIUS) {
        this.CORNER_RADIUS = CORNER_RADIUS;
        requestLayout();

    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        maskPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
        maskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    private static final String TAG = "RoundImageView";

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Bitmap offscreenBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas offscreenCanvas = new Canvas(offscreenBitmap);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        Log.i(TAG, "draw: " + CORNER_RADIUS);
        cornerRadius = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, CORNER_RADIUS, metrics);
        Log.i(TAG, "draw cornerRadius: " + cornerRadius);
        super.draw(offscreenCanvas);

        if (oldRadius != cornerRadius || isFirstTime) {
            maskBitmap = createMask(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            isFirstTime = false;
            oldRadius = cornerRadius;
        }

        offscreenCanvas.drawBitmap(maskBitmap, 0f, 0f, maskPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(offscreenBitmap, 0f, 0f, paint);
    }

    private Bitmap createMask(int width, int height) {
        Bitmap mask = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mask);

        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        Log.i(TAG, "createMask: cornerRadius: " + cornerRadius);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, width, height), cornerRadius, cornerRadius, paint);

        return mask;
    }
}
```

OnCreate method of Activity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainFrm = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainFrm);
        screnshot = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_screenshot);


        frm1 = (RoundCornerFramelayout) findViewById(R.id.frm1);
        frm2 = (RoundCornerFramelayout) findViewById(R.id.frm2);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_screenshot);
        seek_round = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_round);
        seek_round.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                frm1.setCORNER_RADIUS(i);
                frm2.setCORNER_RADIUS(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                screnshot.setImageBitmap(getMainFrameBitmap(mainFrm));
            }
        });
    }


    private Bitmap getMainFrameBitmap(FrameLayout view) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
                view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

xml file of Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.lcom56.roundcornerimagedemo.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainFrm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.example.pc.roundcornerimagedemo.RoundCornerFramelayout
                android:id="@+id/frm1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/pic1" />
            </com.example.pc.roundcornerimagedemo.RoundCornerFramelayout>

            <com.example.pc.roundcornerimagedemo.RoundCornerFramelayout
                android:id="@+id/frm2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/pic1" />
            </com.example.pc.roundcornerimagedemo.RoundCornerFramelayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek_round"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="250" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_screenshot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:text="Take Screenshot" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_screenshot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_screenshot"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```